# Exercise on radical ideal and formal derivatives

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

I need some help for solving the following exercise, because at the moment I'm a little bit lost and don't know where to start.

> Given a field $k$ with $\mathrm{char}(k)=0$ and a polynomial $f\in k[x_1,...,x_n]$, where $f=f_{1}^{d_1}f_2^{d_2}\cdots f_m^{d_m}$ with the $f_i$'s being distinct, irreducible, consider the principal ideal $(f)$. I want to show that the radical $\sqrt{(f)}$ equals the principal ideal $(f')$ with $$f'=\frac{f}{\gcd(f,f_{x_1},...,f_{x_n})}$$
>   where $f_{x_i}$ denotes the formal derivative of $f$ by $x_i$.

A starting point and/or a little hint would be very nice.

Edit: I only know that by definition $\sqrt{(f)}=\{g\in k[x_1,...,x_n]|\exists M\exists h:g^M=hf\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you know that $\sqrt{(f)}=(f_1\cdots f_m)$. Then the question reduces to show $$\gcd(f,f_{x_1},\dots,f_{x_n})=f_1^{d_1-1}\cdots f_m^{d_m-1}.$$ Can you prove this?

Comment: Well I tried but with no success so far. Also I don't see why $\sqrt{(f)}\subseteq(f_1...f_m)$

Comment: @see If $g^k\in (f)$ then $f\mid g^k$, so $f_i\mid g^k$ for all $i$. But $f_i$ irreducible implies $f_i\mid g$ for all $i$, so $f_1\cdots f_m\mid g$.

Comment: @see Try to find out $\gcd(f,f')$ when $n=1$, that is, $f$ is a polynomial in one variable.

Comment: What I am trying to do now is calculating the formal derivative and then looking for common factors of $f$ and $f'$. But where will I need that $\mathrm{char}(k)=0$?

Comment: @see Recall that $(x^n)'=nx^{n-1}$. What's going on if $\mathrm{char}(k)=p\mid n$?

Comment: I get $\sum_{i=1}^ma_if_i^{a_i-1}f_i'\prod_{j\neq i}f_i^{a_i}=\prod_{i=1}^mf_i^{a_i-1}\sum_{i=1}^ma_if_i'\prod_{j\neq i}f_i$. I don't know.

Comment: I think I have to prove now that $gcd(f_1...f_m, \sum_{i=1}^ma_if_i'\prod_{j\neq i}f_i)=1$

Comment: @see Exactly! But isn't this more or less obvious? For instance, $f_1$ divides all the products in that sum excepting $a_1f_1'f_2\cdots f_m$. Can $f_1\mid f_1'f_2\cdots f_m$?

Comment: I don't see it sorry. Do I need irreducibility again? I guess I have a poor intuitive understanding of how to use this property at the moment. Also I still don't know what do do with the characteristic zero, as far as I know this only means that every algebraic extension of k is separable.

Comment: Oh well and separable polynomials and their formal derivative have gcd=1

Comment: So if I have that $f_i\nmid f_1'f_2...f_m$, why does this mean that $f_1$ doesn't divide the sum?

Comment: I think I've already explained this in a previous comment when I said "$f_1$ divides all the products in that sum excepting...".

Comment: I don't understand this explanation

Comment: Try to see what's going on for $m=2$.

Comment: Well assuming $f_1$ would divide the sum I would have $gf_1=a_1f_1'f_2+a_2f_1f_2'$ for some polynomial $g$. I don't see why this can't be. $4$ doesn't divide $6$ but does divide $12$. So I guess this has again something to do with $f_1$ being irreducible, but I don't see what exactly.

Comment: @see Well, this tends to be longer than necessary: of course we use that $f_1$ is irreducible! This is why $f_1\nmid f_1'f_2$. Otherwise $f_1\mid f_1'$ (impossible for degree reasons) or $f_1\mid f_2$ (impossible since both are irreducible and different).

Comment: I did understand both of these before. What I don't understand is that for $f_1$ to divide the sum $a_1f_1'f_2+a_2f_1f_2'$ it has to divide both summands.

Comment: Because $f_1$ already divides $a_1f_1f_2'$!!! In your notation: $(g-a_2f_2')f_1=a_1f_1'f_2\implies f_1\mid f_1'f_2$.

Comment: I think I finally finished the proof, but I'm still not sure where I needed that $char(k)=0$. I thought it was for $f_1\nshortmid f_1'$, but you wrote this follows already for degree reasons. So where did I use it (without knowing)?

Comment: Oh well, and I don't know why $f_1 \nmid
 \sum a_if_i'\prod_{j\neq i}f_i$ implies $\gcd(f_1,\sum a_if_i'\prod_{j\neq i}f_i)=1$. If you could help me with those two things I'm done.

Comment: 1. If $char(k)\ne0$ then $a_1$ (say) can be $0$ and in this case $f_1$ can divide the sum of those products. 2. $f_1$ is irreducible, so its only divisors are $1$ and $f_1$. (I think with some more effort from your part we could have reduced this huge number of comments.)

Comment: Thank you. Regarding 2., I only know the definition that if $f_1$ is irreducible this means that for $f=gh$ either $f$ is constant or $g$ is constant. For example couldn't $f=2*g$ for some $g$? This is the first time I hear something about its only divisors being 1 and $f_1$.

Comment: Well, a constant polynomial count as $1$ when you consider the $\gcd$. For instance, $\gcd(2,X)=1$ in $\mathbb Q[X]$, but we also have $2\mid X$ since $X=2(\frac12X)$, so $\gcd(2,X)=2$. Which one is correct?

Comment: Both I suppose. And being coprime then means that one of those gcds is 1. Sorry to bother you but I have to ask about the characterstic again. I would have assumed that it's implicit all the $a_i$'s aren't $0$, because otherwise my factorization of $f$ wouldn't be unique. However, I don't see how the characteristic is related to $a_i$ at all.

Comment: And so when you write the only divisors of $f_1$ are $f_1$ and $1$, you include all multiples of $f_1$ and all constants in this statement? I'm just asking because I want to know if this is somehow jargon.

Comment: @see Yes. The invertible elements are associate with $1$. (About the characteristic: the $a_i$ are certainly non-zero, but when take the derivative they appear as coefficients in a sum; for instance, the derivative of $f^2$ is zero if characteristic is $2$.)

Comment: I know you shouldn't normally say this in the comments but thank you anyway. I learned a lot from this.